# Expected value of product of sample moments (from a normal sample)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be iid r.v. normally distributed, with mean $3$ and
>   variance $1$. Define $P_n$ as the product of the first two sample moments, i.e.
>   $$P_n = \left(\frac1n\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i\right)\left(\frac1n\sum_{i = 1}^n
> X_i^2\right)$$
>   Define $m$ and $s$ as the mean and variance of $P_n$. What values should $m$
>   and $s$ approximate?

Sum of normals is normal, while sum of squared normal is a chi-squared
distribution (non-central in this case)
$$P_n = \frac1{n^2}XY$$
with
$$\begin{align*}
X &\sim \mathcal N(3n, 1)\\
Y &\sim \chi^2_{n,3n}
\end{align*}$$
and $X$ and $Y$ are not independent because they are calculated on the same
sample.

Therefore
$$\mathbb E[P_n] = \frac1{n^2}(\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[Y] +
\operatorname{Cov}[X, Y])$$
and while I can calculate the first term, I am stuck on the second one as if I
use $\operatorname{Cov}[X, Y] = \mathbb E[(X - \mathbb E[X])(Y - \mathbb
E[Y])]$ I am right back to $\mathbb E[XY]$, which I'm trying to calculate.

I have no idea about the variance of $P_n$. Any hints?

EDIT: I realized that I can expand the product of sums as a Cauchy product. I'm trying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A product of sums can be rewritten as a double sum. In this case, there will be $n^2$ products of the form $X_i X^2_j$.

Since the sample is iid, $\mathbb E[X_i X^2_j] = \mathbb E[X_i] \mathbb E[X^2_j] = 3 \cdot 10 = 30$. Therefore, since expectation is linear,
$$\mathbb E[P_n] = \frac1{n^2} 30 n^2 \to 30$$

As for the variance, the same reasoning applies, and
$$\operatorname{Var}[P_n] = \frac1{n^4} \operatorname{Var}[X_i X^2_j] n^2 = \frac{480}{n^2} \to 0$$

For the general case $X_i \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ the variance will tend to zero just the same, while the expected value can be calculated using the formulas for the first two moments (there's a table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)):
$$\mathbb E[P_n] = \mu(\mu^2 + \sigma^2)$$

Comment: I was really overcomplicating things with that noncentral Chi-squared distribution.